# input type=range is not stretching in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

Here is an example. I'd like to have the slider stretched to the whole width of the parent container. The code below looks as I want in Chrome but in Firefox the slider is not stretching. However I cannot find any bugs on their tracker open against that issue, maybe I am missing something?

```css
#block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
  align-items: stretch;
}

input {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id=block>
  <input type=range />
</div>
```

Comment: Please review and comment on my answer, and let me know if something is unclear or missing. If not, then it would be great if you could accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A flex container with *column* direction, and as the default value of `align-items` is `stretch`, will stretch the flex items to fill its container along its cross axis, which is the same as its width.

So in your case it should work as is, though in Firefox, Edge and IE that is not the case. They all need `width: 100%` for the `input` of type `range` to fill the container.

As a comparison, `input` of type `text` and `checkbox`, and `textarea`, do stretch cross browser, but again `input` of typ `checkbox` doesn't in Firefox.

Whether Firefox (and Edge/IE) is correct or has a bug I can't say yet. I have searched all over and can't find a straight answer to that, but as soon as I do, I will update this answer.

So as of today, I recommend to set the width to 100%, and if Chrome is correct, no harm done and it can be removed later on.

```css
#block {
  /* width: 100%;              not needed since it is the default */
  height: 100%;             /* as its parent doesn't have a height, 
                               this doesn't do anything */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
  /* align-items: stretch;     this is the defalt and can be omitted */
}

input, textarea, span {
  background-color: yellow;

  width: 100%;              /* make FF/Edge/IE stretch input range */
  
  margin: 0;                /* remove any default margin an element might have */
  padding: 0;               /* remove any default padding an element might have */

  box-sizing: border-box;   /* include border an element might have in the set width */
}
```

```html
<div id=block>
  <input type=range />
  
  <!-- added these for comparison -->
  <input type=checkbox />
  <input type=text value="Input text"/>
  <textarea>Textarea</textarea>
  <span>Span</span>
  
</div>
```

Comment: In the first variant you've forgotten to add `margin: 0` as @Tobi did in another answer. The second variant doesn't suit my needs - I need vertical flexing. However, again, it doesn't answer the question - is it a bug in Firefox or what?

Comment: @Grief Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the width of the `<input>` tag to 100% to get what you want!

```css
#block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 0;
}

input {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id=block>
  <input type=range />
</div>
```

Comment: You've also added `margin: 0` because without it input will overflow the container. It is better to make intermediate `div` to have non-zero margins. However it doesn't answer the question, is it a bug in Firefox or I am incorrectly using flexbox model?